# How to hide a div if another has no content

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have some code where I need to hide a div if another is empty.
Basically, if .plant_profile_link has no content, hide .plant_profile_display

My attempt

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (!$.trim($(".plant_profile_link").html()) == true)
    $(".plant_profile_display").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_text_inner">
  <div class="plant_profile_display">Bobo</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- .et_pb_text -->
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_7_tb_body  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">


  <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
    <div class="plant_profile_link"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
    <div class="plant_profile_link"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what type of element plant_profile_link would contain?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update the HTML with relevant examples in a [mcve]

Comment: It seems the code works, but it is REALLY ugly. Don't negate and then compare to true

`if ($(".plant_profile_link").text().trim() === "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works if we add jQuery

I would user toggle

```js
$(function() {
   $(".plant_profile_display").toggle($(".plant_profile_link").text().trim() !== "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et_pb_text_inner">
  <div class="plant_profile_display">Bobo</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- .et_pb_text -->
<div class="et_pb_module et_pb_text et_pb_text_7_tb_body  et_pb_text_align_left et_pb_bg_layout_light">


  <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
    <div class="plant_profile_link"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="et_pb_text_inner">
    <div class="plant_profile_link"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works great, but there is an oddity - the content that is in the div being hidden is a link.  Since adding the code, the link lo longer works??  Obviously this is on links that are being shown.
This is the site, just in case you wanted to look:
https://hydrangeaderby.co.uk/paniculata-brussels-lace-de-belder-1975/

Comment: Your put the code before jQuery library. Put it AFTER you load jQuery. If you hide the link, the link does not work - is that not the aim of this code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this suits you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $plantLinks = $('.plant_profile_link')
  var $plantDisplay = $('.plant_profile_display')
 if($plantLinks.children().length > 0 || $plantLinks.text().length > 0) {
   $plantDisplay.show();
 } else {
   $plantDisplay.hide();
 }
});
```